# salesforce Change Data Capture not sending change event

Tags: salesforce, cometd, change-data-capture

I am using firebase functions to subscribe to change events for opportunity using specified cometD. my handshake all is working but the change is not received at all. i have made sure that in setup Opportunity object is selected. Any advice on what else to check or debug as why nothing is happening?

```
export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest(async(request, response) => {
    functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
   
    const data = {
        "url": "https://XX.salesforce.com",
        "accessToken": "XXX"

    }

    await cometd_setup(data)
    functions.logger.log("cometd_setup_done")

    await cometd.handshake(function (handshake:any) {
    if (handshake.successful) {
       functions.logger.log("successful opty sending data")
       cometd.subscribe('/data/OpportunityChangeEvents', cometd_processdata)
    } else {
        logger.info('Handshake failed', handshake);
    }
})

   response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

the method that process data is currently simply doing a console log as below

```
var cometd_processdata = function (server_data:any) {
    // Do something more useful with the data
    functions.logger.info("got new data:", server_data);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The [name of the subscription channel](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_subscribe_channels.htm) for Change Data Capture (CDC) events on standard objects is `/data/<Standard_Object_Name>ChangeEvent`. For an `Opportunity` standard object, the CDC channel is `/data/OpportunityChangeEvent` (no `s` on the end)

Comment: This definitely was one issue and now i am seeing "Successful opty sending data" getting printed in the logs. As a next step i updated one of the opportunity but i do not see the cometd"_processdata being called at all. What i am missing?

Comment: @Moblize IT We recommend opening a new question. The first step in troubleshooting CometD/Salesforce issues with an external client is to isolate the issue. A good approach for doing so is to implement your listener/subscription in Salesforce, first via an on-platform client with triggers, then off-platform with Salesforce-blessed client such as EMP Connector. The [Change Data Capture tutorial on Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/change-data-capture) covers both of these. You'll have a better idea where to look next after that.